# Can a Turing machine compute the outcome of any machine that is less powerful than a Turing machine?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, computation-models

It is known that a Turing machine cannot predict the outcome of another Turing machine. Given a machine $M$ less powerful than any Turing machine (i.e. able to decide less languages, i.e. a subset of langauges, than any Turing machine), does there exist a Turing machine $T$ which can always compute $M$ such that $T(M, x) = M(x)$?

Comment: Duplicate http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/51863/is-the-halting-problem-always-decidable-for-non-universal-programs.
The question was edited, but the answers there are well fitted for your question. Some concrete examples of natural models are given (counter machines). See the answer by David for a simple obviously weaker model with undecidable halting (or checking output) problem.

Comment: "a turing machine cannot predict the outcome of another turing machine" -- that sentence as is is wrong. There are certainly TMs that can "predict" "outcome" for *some* TMs. Your intuition is flawed.

Comment: Similarly, what is "**a** machine less powerful then **a** TM"? Any single machine is ... not all that powerful.

Comment: @Raphael, please don't nitpick over matters of semantics. The meaning is clear as is: a Turing machine cannot predict the outcome of an *arbitrary* Turing machine.

Comment: Damnit, Alan Turing deserves a capital letter.

Comment: What do you mean by "decide less languages"? Fewer in number? A subset? It's perfectly possible to have a machine that can decide only one language (e.g., the Turing machine halting problem) but where that language cannot be decided by any Turing machine.

Comment: What I'm asking really isn't very hard to understand. The straightforward question is: for *any* machine that is sub-Turing-complete, is there *always* some Turing machine that can output the outcome of this machine without running into a contradiction like the halting problem?

Comment: And by "less powerful" I do mean "subset", not "fewer in number" -- apologies if that wasn't abundantly clear.

Comment: @JeromeBaek You are asking something that is either barely a question or very basic. Hence, I suspect that "nitpicks" may be all of the issue here. (I know that they often are.) Maybe if you used more precise language we could get to another level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any model of computation, say a class of Arbitrary Automata $\mathcal{A}$, so that $F_{\mathcal{A}} \subseteq \mathrm{RE}$, i.e. this model is sub-Turing-complete.

Since TMs are an admissible numbering and $\mathcal{A}$ is a numbering of some set of (semi-)computable functions, for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$ there is a Turing machine $f(A)$ with $F_A = F_{f(A)}$ -- and we know that this compiler $f$ is computable.

By the existence of a universal Turing machine $U$, we get that $U(\langle f(A) \rangle, x) = A(x)$ for all $x$. Applying the s-m-n theorem gives us a TM $T$ with $T(\langle A \rangle, x) = U(\langle f(A) \rangle, x) = A(x)$.